# Coordinate Independent Integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

First of all I would like to apologize in advance if I lack conveying my question properly in a formal mathematical manner. I am currently taking a course on "Calculus on Manifolds" and we are reviewing differential forms for later use in the course. However one thing that keeps bothering me is that how and why differential forms are coordinate free?

Comment: Might be [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/984284/what-exactly-does-differential-forms-are-coordinate-free-mean).

Comment: Title related to question?

Comment: The lecturer pointed out that since forms live independent of coordinates it is of importance since it in a way helps one to integrate independent of coordinates hence generalizing. The book we follow makes a similar statement too.

Comment: I did check the related threads however I could not be able to convince myself

Comment: Yes, you probably should change the title. Although we *compute* with differential forms in coordinates, one can define a $k$-form on an $n$-dimensional manifold in a totally coordinate-independent way. For example, it will "eat" $k$ vector fields and spit out a smooth function.